# Error while generating a *Lexer class for large Xtext file

Tags: xtext

I have two Xtext(version-2.11) Projects, called A and B.  B is dependent on A. Both of these Xtext projects have large Xtext file.(>1000 lines of code)

When I try to generate Xtext Artifacts for Project B, it gives me below error:

> 28166 [main] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating common infrastructure
>   28171 [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - Problems running workflow org.xtext.example.mydsl.GenerateMyDslB: 
>        org.eclipse.xtext.util.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: b.parent\b..\b\src-gen\org\xtext\example\mydsl\parser\antlr\internal\InternalMyDslBLexer.java (The system cannot find the file specified)
>       at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess.readTextFile(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.java:257)

I have tried a various kind of solution from the web, but it didn't work.

For example:
mwe2 file modification with

```
parserGenerator = {
                antlrParam = "-Xmaxinlinedfastates"
                antlrParam = "65534"
                antlrParam = "-Xmaxswitchcaselabels"
                antlrParam = "32000"
                antlrParam = "-Xminswitchalts"
                antlrParam = "1"
                options = auto-inject {
                    classSplitting = true
                    fieldsPerClass = "40"
                    methodsPerClass = "40"
                }
            }
```

Does someone has any pointer about this error?

Comment: can you please share you updated sample project and the complete log. and you should play with the antlr timeouts

Comment: @ChristianDietrich: Unfortunately, it would not be possible for me to share the sample project due to some copyright constraints. I will check with the antlr options, do you suggest any other things ?

Comment: cant you create an artifical grammar that shows the same problem?

Comment: I am already in process to do that, it will take some time, will update once done.

Comment: @ChetanLaddha ever got to a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Safron sorry I managed it via some workaround which was very specific to our case.

Comment: @ChetanLaddha In the meantime I've solved my issue. It was caused by an ambiguity in the grammer. I guess the error message was just a red herring; could be done better. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue gets resolved by resolving ambiguity in the grammar.